# Is there a JavaScript or posssibly Python/Django web service to geocode street addresses?

Tags: javascript, python, api, geolocation, geocoding

Is there a generic JavaScript or possibly Python/Django or other open source web service or API to look up a geolocation given a street address? http://www.braincastexception.com/wp7-web-services-first-part-geocodeservice/ does what I want, apparently in C#. Is the like available from JavaScript or open source projects that can be queried?

ATdhvaanckse,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com/) a free an open source geo service.

Everyone will tell you to use the Google Maps API but read the [terms of use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

> (g) No Use of Content without a Google Map. You must not use or
>   display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are
>   explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation, or
>   through written permission from Google. In any event, you must not use
>   or display the Content on or in conjunction with a non-Google map. For
>   example, you must not use geocodes obtained through the Service in
>   conjunction with a non-Google map. As another example, you must not
>   display Street View imagery alongside a non-Google map, but you may
>   display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because
>   the Maps APIs Documentation explicitly permits you to do so.

So with the Google API you **must use a Google Map**. So if you need a map you're OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). You can find an example of what you want [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).

Answer (score 1):

You can circumvent the restrictive TOS that Google, Bing, and other providers have by using [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api). I work at [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) and help to maintain it.

While Google will only approximate the address (in other words, return results for addresses which don't exist), LiveAddress will verify the existence of the address and return only valid results, and a handful of other valuable data about it.

Python sample code here: https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/tree/master/python

Javascript examples here:
http://jsfiddle.net/user/smartystreets/fiddles/ and https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/tree/master/jQuery (uses jQuery) and https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/tree/master/javascript.

Comment: This question made me regret I could only choose one answer...